# Are arguments in python functions passed as tuple?

Tags: function, python-3.x, arguments, language-specifications

Let `f` be a function with 2 arguments. I do not really understand why the syntax:

```
f(1,2,)
```

actually works (note the ending comma)? It looks like the arguments are seen as a tuple, but in this case, if `g` is a function with 1 argument, why `g(1)` is working (instead of `g(1,)` in the same way we have to write (1,) to get the tuple with only one element)?

I think it's a Python's specification question but I do not know where to search.

Comment: I'm going to need you to reword this. I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. The positional arguments are a list `args*`. neither `f(1)`, or `f(1,)` should not work for a function definition that specifies two arguments. You should see `f() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: although `l = [1,2,]` is a valid list assignment

Comment: The grammar for calls is described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-call).

Comment: I've reformulated: I'm not interessed in the arg* or key** arguments, but in the way the classical args are represented.

Must I understant from your last answer that the arguments are indeed list ?

Comment: Ok thanks @Kevin . Is there any deep reason that make the spec allows this trailing comma?

Comment: I don't see any explanation in the documentation, but my guess is: it makes it easier to make changes to function calls that appear over multiple lines. For example, if you want to change the order of arguments of `f( [newline] 1, [newline] 2, [newline])`, then you only need to cut one line and paste it in its new position. If trailing commas were disallowed, you would have to cut, paste, and delete/retype commas in the appropriate spots.

Comment: A lot of the grammar and pep8 related items are geared to making editing easier. If you are using `vim` or another editor that makes cutting and pasting entire lines easy. This can be a pretty big time saver because it requires several keystrokes to add or remove the comma.

Comment: Ok ! Thanks ;p I would like to "+1" your answers but it appears that I don't have enough reputation :(.